# "История, которую увидит свет" или "История, которая увидит свет"?

Tags: грамотная-речь, согласование, спп

История, **которую** или **которая** увидит свет, будет рассказывать о...

Comment: Если вам дан (или будет дан) исчерпывающий ответ, пожалуйста, отметьте его [как принятый](/help/accepted-answer) (галочка рядом с ответом) и поставьте ему значок ▲.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Увидеть свет - фразеологизм.  Быть опубликованным, изданным. **Благодаря вашему вниманию, поддержке, а может быть, и защите, моя «Педагогическая поэма» увидела свет, да ещё в таком совершенно уже незаслуженном соседстве с вашей пьесой (Макаренко. Письмо А. М. Горькому, 7 марта.**

**История, которая увидит свет (которая будет опубликована), будет рассказывать о..**